# E:/ RecyclerView: No Adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, json

I'm retrieving my data from API through JSON parsing and display it is an `recyclerview` , whenever I make an API call the error occurs in logcat says: `"E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"` when I run my app in my physical device, but when I run my app on emulator it works fine for me, so what is the problem or reason behind this?, please help!

Here is my Code:

```
private void showData() {

    showDialog();

    tenderList = new ArrayList<>();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    tenderList.add(new Tender(
                            jsonObject.getInt("tender_id"),
                            jsonObject.getString("trnumber"),
                            jsonObject.getString("nameofwork"),
                            jsonObject.getString("estimate_value"),
                            jsonObject.getString("city"),
                            jsonObject.getString("state"),
                            jsonObject.getString("closing_date")
                    ));
                    Log.d(String.valueOf(getContext()),String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("tender_id")));
                }

                final TenderAdapter tenderAdapter = new TenderAdapter(getContext(),tenderList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(tenderAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(String.valueOf(getContext()),e.getMessage());
            }
            dismissDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String e = error.getMessage();
            Log.d(String.valueOf(getContext()),e == null ?"":e);
            dismissDialog();
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);
}
```

> Fragment code

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_live_tender,container,false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    showData();
    return view;
}
```

> **TenderAdapter**

```
public class TenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TenderAdapter.TenderViewHolder> {

    private List<Tender> tenderList;
    private Context context;

    public TenderAdapter(Context context,List<Tender> tenderList) {
        this.tenderList = tenderList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TenderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_tender_list,null);
        return new TenderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TenderViewHolder tenderViewHolder, int i) {
        Tender tender = tenderList.get(i);

        tenderViewHolder.trno.setText(tender.getTrNo());
        tenderViewHolder.tenderDetails.setText(tender.getTenderDetails());
        tenderViewHolder.tenderVal.setText(tender.getTenderValue());
        tenderViewHolder.city.setText(tender.getCity());
        tenderViewHolder.state.setText(tender.getState());
        tenderViewHolder.closingDate.setText((CharSequence) tender.getClosingDate());

        tenderViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailListingActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tenderList.size();
    }

    public class TenderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView trno,tenderDetails,tenderVal,city,state,closingDate;

        public TenderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            trno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTrNo);
            tenderDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTenderDetails);
            tenderVal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTenderValue);
            city = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
            state = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvState);
            closingDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClosingDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your `TenderAdapter` code with question

Comment: yes for sure @NileshRathod sir

Comment: done, please re-check it @NileshRathod sir

Comment: Use this `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_tender_list,viewGroup,false);` inside your `onCreateViewHolder()`

Comment: tried it , but still not work @NileshRathod

Comment: try to check what you getting in your `response` inside `onResponse()` method print in log

Comment: check in adapter size of the list

Comment: Populate your adapter in `getActivity().runOnUIThread()` method. Also must be sure that _tenderList.size()_ should not be _0_

Comment: No there is no response inside log @NileshRathod

Comment: @DarshitAnjaria r u share you aee retrieving data from API call

Comment: i think you should add recyclerView.setAdapter(tenderAdapter); inside onCreate

Comment: yes because the data is retrieving in emulator but not in real device @NileshRathod

Comment: ok let's try @MadLeo

Comment: That's not work @MadLeo

Answer (score 0):

check following

> -> internet permission in manifest
>
> -> are you getting log data in `onResponse` or `onError`
>
> -> wifi/data is turned on or not

Comment: internet permission is checked, no log regarding to onResponse or onError, Mobile data is already turn on

Answer (score 0):

Create global object of adapter,initialize and assign it to recylerview in **onCreate**.
Don't assign adapter in API response.
Just change some code,
Create constructor in adapter with context,

```
 public TenderAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }
```

Don't pass arraylist in constructor,
Just create one method on adapter,

```
public void addData(ArrayList<Tender> items) {
        this.arrayList = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And call this method from your API response.

```
adapter.addData(tenderList)
```

Comment: Have you posted your code on any place like GitHub pg bitbucket?so I can check hole code.

Comment: if you use skype then give me your skype id @Kintan

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching the adapter in the **onCreateView()** method, you are doing it in your **showData()** method, which is wating for some **response** from the web, essentially you are making a **network call**. If all is normal, then this network call is most probably happening on a **network thread** and is asynchronous, because android doesn't allow long operations in main thread.

What I mean is, the program control is not waiting for your **showData()** method to finish, and **onCreateView()** is finishing first.

That's why you get an adapter not attached error

**Update**
This error does not affect performance, but if you really want it out of your logs, you can follow below steps

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

do the above in you onCreateView() method. And you can separate the logic of setting the list using a setter.

```
adapter.setYourList(yourList)
```

Just make sure that when you call this setter you directly or indirectly invalidate the present layout, otherwise your recycler layout won't show.

Comment: This Error generally doesn't affect performance, you must be getting the layout once data is successfully retrieved from the network call

Comment: yup, but in emulator it works fine, and in physical device I'm waiting for long time, but it does not retrieve

Comment: Check my updated answer. Are you sure you are getting data, you can log your results to check it

Comment: So the problem you have is not with recycler view, it is with the network call you are making. Why don't you change your question or add another question. And try to accept this answer

Comment: but why when I run the same code in Emulator the data is showing in log as well as in recycler view